User desactivated after VPS migration/restart
After a VPS forced migration by host, main user ubuntu is desactivated.
VPS restart at 10PM and /etc/shadow file have been modified at 10PM.
Change is the ! added:
ubuntu:!$
Host says it can't be them. Can restarting Ubuntu (or an update) may disable a user?

Rebooting Ubuntu or applying updates would not disable a user.  It is possible here that what ended up happening was their migration script made changes.  There's nothing inside Ubuntu that would do this. I assume you have alternative access to the system to see the data, you can just set a password on the ubuntu user and regain access using sudo passwd ubuntu and set a password. It'll remove the lock on the account, etc.

Thanks @ThomasWard. I've found in auth.log password for 'ubuntu' changed by 'root'. After some research I think I understand that the cloud-init package may be the culprit

Yeah, cloud-init if it received config to push will do that, but by default it won't change passwords.  I would also consider creating a second account that isn't the default ubuntu user that has sudo permission, etc. and use that instead of the default 'ubuntu' account.

I think I'm in this situation: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-init/+bug/2075968. Thanks @ThomasWard
